# Surjective homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Let $\phi$ be an homomorphism from a group G into a group G', if i know that its range contains a set that generates G' can I affirme that the $\phi$ is surjective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by the fact that the image of a homomorphism is a subgroup.

Comment: Thank you, forgot about that. And if I change the groups for algebras the same thing goes right?

Comment: If you mean generators in the sense of subalgebras, then yes. If you mean generators in the sense of ideals, then not necessarily.